# C++: Disable old style cast warnings in CMake

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

I am interfacing with an old code base which extensively uses old style casts (thousands). I am trying to disable these warnings in Cmake, but it just isn't working (I do not want to see 1000s of warnings, nor do I care to fix the root cause). To do this, I assume that I should be setting `-Wno-old-style-cast`. I tried doing this in 3 separate places in the `CMakeLists.txt` file, but to no avail. Here is the complete file:

```
set(example "train")
project(${example} CXX)

# Python
message(STATUS "We are going to force it to use Python 3. If you change this, you will need to remove the build folder and reload the cmake project.")
find_package(PythonLibs 3 EXACT)
find_package(PythonInterp 3 EXACT)

# PCL library
find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-old-style-cast")
set(CXX_COMMON_FLAGS "${CXX_COMMON_FLAGS} -Wno-old-style-cast")

add_executable(${example} src/${example}.cpp)
target_compile_options(${example} PUBLIC -Wno-old-style-cast)
target_link_libraries(${example} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(${example} PRIVATE include/ ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

I am compiling on Ubuntu 18.04 with GCC 7.4.0. I see thousands of errors like this:

```
/usr/include/python3.7m/object.h:118:49: warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]
 #define Py_TYPE(ob)             (((PyObject*)(ob))->ob_type)
```

### EDIT:

The output of `make VERBOSE=1` yields:

```sh
/usr/bin/c++  -DDISABLE_LIBUSB_1_0 -DDISABLE_PCAP -DDISABLE_PNG -DPCL_NO_PRECOMPILE=0 -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -Dqh_QHpointer -DvtkRenderingContext2D_AUTOINIT="1(vtkRenderingContextOpenGL2)" -DvtkRenderingCore_AUTOINIT="3(vtkInteractionStyle,vtkRenderingFreeType,vtkRenderingOpenGL2)" -isystem /usr/include/vtk-7.1 -isystem /usr/include/freetype2 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -isystem /usr/local/include/pcl-1.9 -isystem /usr/include/eigen3 -I/home/bob/Desktop/choc/include -I/usr/include/python3.7m -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -isystem /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++  -Wno-old-style-cast    -Wno-old-style-cast -march=native -msse4.2 -mfpmath=sse -fPIC -std=gnu++14 -o CMakeFiles/train.dir/src/train.cpp.o -c /home/bob/Desktop/choc/src/train.cpp
```

Comment: The CMake-global variable is called `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.

Comment: I believe you want to disable the warnings, not the casts.

Comment: @molbdnilo What flag do you think I want?

Comment: `-Wold-style-cast`.  You probably need `-Wno-old-style-cast`.

Comment: That seems unintuitive to me. I thought `-Wx` means "warn me of `x`" and `-Wno-x` meas "do not warn me of `x`"

Comment: Maybe you need `-Werror=old-style-cast`.

Comment: Wait. That did not fix the problem. Let me rephrase the question in case there is some confusion

Comment: Run `make`  with `VERBOSE=1` option and check whether your `-Wno-old-style-cast` option is **actually used** when given warning arise.

Comment: Yes I do see it there. I will update the question with one of the full commands.

Comment: Are these casts in your project's code or in an "external" library you are using? IN case it's the latter, you can add `SYSTEM` when you do `target_include_directories` or `target_link_libraries` which will automatically suppress all warnings in headers in include directories defined by that target

Answer (score 0):

Some libraries of pcl set -Wold-style-cast warnings using Diagnostic Pragmas. For this reason this warnings should appear whatever you set in you cmake configuration. Disabling it using pragmas before of including pcl headers solved the problem in my case.

```
#include <pcl/surface/concave_hull.h>

#ifdef __GNUC__
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wold-style-cast"
#endif
```